# My variable is defined but Julia is saying it isn't?

Tags: scope, julia

When I run this its able to use the m variable to give me a table of values, but then when i ask it to print m it says it's undefined? I think it might have to do with the scope?

```
# Solving x - 2^(-x) = 0 via the Trisection Method
# Its exactly like before, but now there are three sections.

# Define the main function, initial brackets [a,b],
# midpoint, and iteration variable.
function main(x)
    return (x - 2^(-x)) 
end

a = 0
b = 1
i = 0

# main loop
while((b - a) > 0.0001)
    m = (a + b) / 2
    r = (1/3)*(2*a + b)
    t = (1/3)*(a + 2*b)
    i += 1
    
    if(main(r) > 0)
        b = r
    elseif(main(t) > 0)
        a = r
        b = t
    else
        a = t
    end
    println(m)
end

# Output
println(m)
#print("after ")
#print(i)
#print(" iterations")
```

Comment: You are working in global scope. This is bad in Julia, and will cause errors (like the one are seeing) and bad performance. Make sure that all the code you call is inside functions.

Answer (score 1):

As you guessed, this is indeed a problem with the scope.

You assign, for the first time, the variable `m` within a `while` block. The `while` block has a scope type of "local (soft)" which means when `m` is not already a local variable (which is the case here) then a new *local* variable `m` is created within the scope of the assignment---the while block in your case. As `m` is now local to the while block, it cannot be used outside this while block, hence the error when you try to `println(m)` outside the scope of the while block.

See [this page](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/variables-and-scoping/) in the Julia documentation on Scopes of Variables for more information.

If you want to use the variable `m` outside the scope of the while block then you can use the `global` keyword at assignment, i.e.

```
while((b - a) > 0.0001)
    global m = (a + b) / 2
    #other code
end

println(m)
```

But as @DNF mentions, you would be better off wrapping everything in function definitions.